# Bayesian statistics given noisy data

Tags: probability, analysis

To be blunt, this is not a good question. I am no statistician, and I don't know what question to ask.

I am rewriting votekick for our game. We have on the order of 10,000 concurrent players and a new votekick is started every 20 seconds, so we have a lot of data.

We keep the following data, we call a vote record, on a player:

```
YB = number of times player voted yes on another who was eventually banned
NB = number of times player voted no on another who was eventually banned
YU = number of times player voted yes on another who has not been banned
NU = number of times player voted no on another who has not been banned
```

In the scenario where a votekick has been called on a suspected cheater, and a list of players have cast their votes on whether to kick the cheater, given those player's vote records (and the entier database of vote records), we want to find the probability that the suspected cheater will be banned in the future.

Effectively, I am trying to write a votekick based on Bayesian statistics. That part is done. The problem is that when computing the Bayesian update values, that is, `P(player A will be banned given player B voted to kick) / P(player A will not be banned given player B voted to kick)`, this can be very noisy. Specifically if player B has no prior data or very little data, that equation becomes `(YB/(YB + NB)) / (YU/(YU + NU))`, which is filled with divisions by 0 and noisy data.

So right now, we try to estimate a set of true values given a player's current vote record. The four true values add to 1, and represent the proportion of the time we expect a player to vote each which way. To compute this, we take every player's vote record. We compute a similarity metric, which is the numeric answer to the question: Given player A's vote record and player B's vote record, what is the probability that player B, at some point in the past, had player A's vote record. We take this to be the weight. In a sum, we take each player in the data base who has a vote record to be player B, and compare to some given player A, and do a weighted average to estimated the true vote stats.

We get k*probablity that playerB held playerA's record at some point in the past by doing the following:

```
local function getProb(a0, b0, c0, d0, a1, b1, c1, d1)
    return nomial(a0, b0, c0, d0)/nomial(a1, b1, c1, d1)
        *nomial(a1 - a0, b1 - b0, c1 - c0, d1 - d0)
```

where nomial is generalized binomial and a0, b0, c0, d0 are player A's vote record and a1, b1, c1, d1 are player B's vote record.

This is not good enough.

Comment: Are you trying to predict which player is which based on voting records, or whether a player is likely to be kicked out of the game based on who has voted?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Whether a player __should__ be kicked given who has voted and which way they have voted. This is subjective, and handwavy but, useful.

Comment: It's not possible to guess without information about what constitutes a kick. For example 10% of players vote to kick, 100 total players vote, etc.

Comment: You are right, but we can make some intuitive assumptions, and those assumptions are going to be better than the basic votekick stuff that we have right now. We can create variables in the system that we can tune based on user feedback.

Comment: I don't think it's a question which can really be answered at this site. You seem to be asking for heuristic methods to guess something which you don't fully specify.